# How to write unit tests for python tornado application?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tornado

I want to try to write some code following TDD practice. I want to create simple app based on python's tornado framework. I was looking through the internet how people write tests for tornado and found something like this:

```
class TestSomeHandler(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def test_success(self):
        response = self.fetch('/something')
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks more like integration tests. Instead of it I'm trying to write simple unit test for some dummy handler. For example such one:

```
class SomeHandler(BaseHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        try:
            from_date = self.get_query_argument("from", default=None)
            datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Incorrect argument value for from_date = %s, should be YYYY-MM-DD" % from_date)
```

And test would look like:

```
class TestSomeHandler(AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    def test_no_from_date_param(self):
        handler = SomeHandler()
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            handler.get()
```

I know I miss at `get()` application and request. Not handled yet how to create them.

But my question is, do people write tests for tornado like in first example or somebody calls handlers inside of app? What pattern to follow? It would be nice if somebody have relevant code to share.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pattern with `AsyncHTTPTestCase` is used mostly because, it makes all the request stuff for you. Of course one can also use `AsyncTestCase` and handle it manually.

AsyncTestCase example. Since it will be testing `get` method that is coroutine, we will use [`gen_test`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/testing.html#tornado.testing.gen_test) to make it a bit simpler. [`RequestHandler`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler) requires `Application` and `HTTPRequest` objects. Because we are not relaying of app's settings, ui_methods, etc. `Application` is a simple mock.

```
from tornado.testing import AsyncTestCase, gen_test
from tornado.web import Application
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPRequest
from unittest.mock import Mock

class TestSomeHandler(AsyncTestCase):

    @gen_test
    def test_no_from_date_param(self):
        mock_application = Mock(spec=Application)
        payload_request = HTTPRequest(
            method='GET', uri='/test', headers=None, body=None
        )
        handler = SomeHandler(mock_application, payload_request)
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            yield handler.get()
```

IMHO it is up to you which pattern to use. I choose `AsyncHTTPTestCase` for http-verb methods (get, post and so on), because:

- it is easier
- consumer of this method is HTTP client, so asserts response code, body make a lot of sense
- it prevents of over-complicated methods

Of course rest of handler's methods tested with `AsyncTestCase`.

Comment: As I understand such flow is not preferable. But in other case I wont be able to test exceptions.

Comment: @viakondratiuk the consumer of the method is some http client (user),  any exception you raised it is just 50x with some message, probably Internal error. It is ok? I dont think so - it shows poor error handling, try to return "return" meaningful errors (even some unified message) and further service calls and debugging will be a lot easier to take.

Comment: Tornado version 6.1 does not have `uri` in the `HTTPRequest`. The first argument should be the `url`. https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#request-objects

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncHTTPTestCase` is designed for tests like your first example, using `self.fetch` instead of instantiating Handlers directly.

`RequestHandler` is not designed to be instantiated by hand without the use of an `Application`, so if you have pieces of functionality that you would prefer to test without the full HTTP stack, this code should generally be in static functions or non-`RequestHandler` classes.

Comment: So, as I understand, I should test handlers with `AsyncHTTPTestCase` and other code, which can throw exceptions and so on, I should isolate it and test separately?

Comment: Yes. The dividing line is up to you: for the exception example given here I'd personally test that over HTTP and verify that it produces the right status code and error message instead of the exception type.